# Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. SDK 23.0

Tags: android

Right from yesterday the moment I updated my SDK, I am unable to install new software in Eclipse(I mean the plugin for 23.0)...It's with the message, "cannot perform operation computing alternate solutions"....

The Error Message is :

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.1.1256982 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.feature.group 23.0.1.1256982)
  Software currently installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.1.1256982 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer 23.0.1.1256982)
    Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
    Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.1.1256982 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.feature.group 23.0.1.1256982)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer [23.0.1.1256982]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer [22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206]
```

Comment: The error says: uninstall `Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.3` before you install `Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.1`

Comment: This is a bug. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72912. Official solution is provided in comment #18 in the issue tracker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same issue. The only workaround for me was to download eclipse manually and install the latest ADT tools. Even downloading a new SDK didn't work as the new ADT eclipse doesn't seem to be creating Activities.

Comment: So then should I uninstall Eclipse first, or just install Eclipse over the old one? It's the same version :/

Comment: If you installed Eclipse manually the last time you can uninstall only ADT plug in and reinstall it. But I would suggest starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72584. Due to a bug, you cannot use the normal update process to upgrade the ADT plugins from version 22 to version 23. Uninstall version 22, then install version 23.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened with me.
In order to fix it. try "Run with Administrator"