# Unable to create activity in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just downloaded eclipse juno and when I create an activity, it isn't showing up in my project. I have tried installing  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ as others have suggested but it comes up with this error:

```
Your original request has been modified.

  "Android Traceview" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android Development Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android DDMS" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android Hierarchy Viewer" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android Native Development Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Tracer for OpenGL ES" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
  Software currently installed: eclipse 23.0.0.1245622 (adtproduct 23.0.0.1245622)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Android Development Toolkit 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 23.0.2.1259578)
    Android Development Toolkit 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 23.0.0.1245622)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: eclipse 23.0.0.1245622 (adtproduct 23.0.0.1245622)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group [23.0.0.1245622]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt [23.0.0.1245622]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt [23.0.2.1259578]
```

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24522870/806267 There is no way around this ATM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with the latest bundle provided by Google. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72912.

- There is no way to update an existing ADT bundle that you might have downloaded.
- You can do one of two options:

  1. Install eclipse from eclipse.org and install ADT by pointing to the update site: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse
  2. Download bundles from here:

> linux 64 bit vm:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip
>
> linux 32 bit vm:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip
>
> mac:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip
>
> win32:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip
>
> win64:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Starting with ADT bundle 23.0.2, you should be able to update to future versions of ADT.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem, was able to solve in this way -

1. Eclipse-->Help-->About Eclipse---->Installation Details
2. Select - Android DDMS, ADT, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android Native Development Tools, Android TraceView and Tracer for OpenGL ES packages. All must be version 22.xx
3. Uninstall all the plugins selected above.
4. Restart Eclipse
5. Install ADT from update site - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/