# How to individually install eclipse, adt and sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

After trying several times to download the adt bundle from the android website which includes adt, sdk and eclipse,I have had no luck. There seems to be an issue with the bundle. My question is, how do I go about installing each bit separately. I have downloaded eclipse and the adt plugin but where does the sdk fit into all of this. Anyone got a step by step guide?

Comment: What's the issue with the bundle ?

Comment: When I make an android application project, it doesn't create any activities. Also when I try to update the software, multiple errors come up.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595811/unable-to-create-activity-in-eclipse

Comment: Why not ust go ahead and create an activity. Its much easier than setting up Eclipse again IMHO.

Comment: That's the problem, when I create an activity, it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading and opening Eclipse, go to Help -> Install new software -> Add.

```
Name - ADT
Location - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse
```

Click ok. Select the `Developer Tools` checkbox and proceed. It will download and install the ADT plugin automatically.

Then click on the "Android SDK manager" button in Eclipse. Select the SDKs you want to download and you are done.

Comment: How do I install the sdk after that?

Comment: Click on the "Android SDK Manager" button on top. The icon is a downward button with an android head.

Comment: So the ADT plugin allows you to get the sdk?

Comment: yes. Once the ADT plugin is installed, you will find all the Android options appearing in Eclipse.