# Eclipse not working with ADT Plug in

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt

I recently bought an SSD(Solid state drive) just for Eclipse. I wanted to have a complete new fresh installation of ADT along with eclipse, so I downloaded the [bundle from here.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

I have downloaded it, extracted, then went into the eclipse folder and ran "eclipse". When the program is opening, I am not presented with this:

[image]

Like it should, but I am presented with this:

[image]

Then once the program is loaded up, it seems like there is no ADT Plug in installed anywhere. I have tried going to Help --> Install new software --> Add --> then downloading it again via https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ but it just says:

[image]

So I tried going to Help --> About --> Installation details then updating, then it prompts me with this:

[image]

If anyone would be able to help me out with this, that would be great.

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522750/cannot-complete-the-install-because-of-a-conflicting-dependency-sdk-23-0/24522870#24522870

Comment: I've tried manually downloading eclipse and installing the plug in but that didn't work.

Comment: It worked for me. What version of eclipse did you download? I currently have that setup working perfectly for me!

Comment: Juno was included in the bundle I downloaded.

Comment: I know there's the newest version of eclipse called "Kepler". Maybe I should try my luck with that?

Comment: That will not work as that already has the ADT plugin installed, you need to download eclipse from : https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and install the ADT plugin. The instructions are available at : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html The latest version if 4.4 (Luna)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 -**
 
This is because previous version of ADT cannot be updated..
you will have first uninstall previous version

Go to `Help > About > Installation Details > Select ADT`
and uninstall..
and after that do whatever you have done till now (install software https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse )

(This can be result in error `Cannot backup eclipse.exe` )

**Option 2 -**
Download new Android Sdk, which comes with new ADT installed.